# How to sum time values in GridView column?

Tags: c#

[This is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRX5I.png) of my `GriView` which is populated from a table in SQL database.

I want to run totals in the footer. I figured it out for the 'Quantity' column but I don't know how to proceed for the 'Time' column.

Here is what I have so far:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TotalQuantity += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Quantity"));
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "TotalQuantity";
        e.Row.Cells[0].Font.Bold = true;

        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = TotalQuantity.ToString();
        e.Row.Cells[1].Font.Bold = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to employ the `System.TimeSpan` data structure. It is likely that the value in the `Time` column is stored as string so you need to convert it a bit and sum the `TimeSpan`s.

```
TimeSpan totalTime = new TimeSpan();

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TotalQuantity += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Quantity"));
        var ts = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Time").ToString(); 
        var t = DateTime.Parse(ts).TimeOfDay;
        totalTime += t;
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "TotalQuantity";
        e.Row.Cells[0].Font.Bold = true;

        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = TotalQuantity.ToString();
        e.Row.Cells[1].Font.Bold = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I can help. Just don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to do this, but this will work as well.

Simply we add your time to a date e.g. `2000/01/01` and we get the seconds count, keep counting seconds and at the end we subtract

You can do the following:

```
static double count = 0;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

DateTime tmp = Convert.ToDateTime("2000/01/01 " + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Time").ToString());
     count += tmp.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime("2000/01/01 00:00:00")).TotalSeconds;
}
```

And to get the result use:

if you want the total seconds just use `count`. if you want to display the total time at the bottom use the below:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("2000/01/01 00:00:00").AddSeconds(count).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```